# Best practices deploying Vue 3 application in Laravel website

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

Current situation:

Website running Laravel 7 with Spark 11. The Spark module has Vue 2 integrated.

New situation

A newly developed Vue3 application needs to be running from the Laravel website, to prevent cor issues.
Obviously, the public Laravel folder is a suitable candidate, but there already are css/js/font folders in there, so would then be a mixed bag.

I created a subfolder in public, and placed everything in there. With everything, I mean:

```
[4.0K]  dist
├── [4.0K]  CSS
│   ├── [ 15K]  app.bdfb0440.css
│   └── [718K]  chunk-vendors.273a2a44.css
├── [4.2K]  favicon.ico
├── [4.0K]  fonts
│   ├── [549K]  materialdesignicons-webfont.1dab7af5.woff
│   ├── [376K]  materialdesignicons-webfont.2474c2c1.woff2
│   ├── [1.2M]  materialdesignicons-webfont.a1c852b2.eot
│   └── [1.2M]  materialdesignicons-webfont.b33ccf64.ttf
├── [ 672]  index.html
└── [4.0K]  js
    ├── [592K]  app.322f5d21.js
    ├── [1.9M]  app.322f5d21.js.map
    ├── [1.2M]  chunk-vendors.05514f76.js
    ├── [5.2M]  chunk-vendors.05514f76.js.map
    ├── [ 12K]  webfontloader.579cd8f3.js
    └── [ 32K]  webfontloader.579cd8f3.js.map
```

I changed the references in the index.html, to reflect the subfolder changes. However, still some errors appear when the webfontloader wants to load stuff.

These are the errors:

```
 load script:41          GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/webfontloader.579cd8f3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

jsonp chunk loading:27 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 461 failed.
(error: http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/webfontloader.579cd8f3.js)
at s.f.j (jsonp chunk loading:27:18)
at ensure chunk:6:25
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at s.e (ensure chunk:5:56)
at Am (webfontloader.js:9:31)
at 4390 (main.js:21:1)
at s (bootstrap:19:32)
at startup:4:87
at s.O (chunk loaded:25:12)
at startup:5:43
```

So I was wondering, might there be some other options to pursue?

Comment: If you don't share what errors you are getting, it is impossible to help you. Update the question with that please

Comment: added some error debug, thanks

Comment: Can you try to manually access the URL and try to see which URL works? The URL it is trying to use is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/webfontloader.579cd8f3.js`, but based on what you said, it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dist/js/webfontloader.579cd8f3.js`

Comment: Yes, that works. It's actually http://127.0.0.1:8000/toolname/js/webfontloader.579cd8f3.js 
toolname is the folder that holds the css/fonts/js folders and the index.html

I did change the other references in the toolname/index.html:

<script defer="defer" src="/toolname/js/chunk-vendors.05514f76.js"></script>
<script defer="defer" src="/toolname/js/app.322f5d21.js"></script>
<link href="/toolname/css/chunk-vendors.273a2a44.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/toolname/css/app.bdfb0440.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I noticed that it does work with assetsDir: 'toolname/', in the vue.config.js, however, now all links in my application refer to / so I need to change that as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding:

assetsDir: 'toolname/',

in the vue.config.js

did the trick. However, now the links in my tool are not functional, but that's a different question. So I'll mark this question solved for now.